# How to go back from 3rd activity to first in Android

Tags: android

I have tab view and in one activity from tab i start my A Activity from A i start B Activity how can i in some case go to back in Tab Activity. 
I Try Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP but it clear my A activity ann all activitys in tab view.

Can anyone give suggestion.

Comment: why not just force the back button pressed with `super.onBackPressed();`

Comment: it not useful for me in my code i automatically close activity after result from server

Answer (score 0):

Try using this it might do the job

```
  Intent parentActivityIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityYouWannaGoTo.class);
  parentActivityIntent.addFlags(
          Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
          Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(parentActivityIntent);
  finish();
```

Comment: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP it not useful for me it clear tab view activities. This like that if i close my app and lunch another activity.

Answer (score 0):

start B using startActivityForResult and when you want to go back to first activity set the result to RESULT_OK. In A onActivityResult check if the result is RESULT_OK call finish().

Comment: I know this way but it is not effective. Suppose if i start 200 activities and i want to go back to first activity it may take time.

Comment: Well in that case just start the first activity from B without any flag, you just add the 201th activity to your stack. This will take no time at all. But if the user has to press 201 times to close the app. A stack should never have that many activity especially if the same activity is already on the stack

Comment: Thanks i do this i can't find another way

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest file set the launch mode of the activity with the tabs to be singleTop (`android:launchMode="singleTop"`). After that when you want to go back to the tab activity use the flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.